# I have a dead battery and my laptop refuses to come out of power saving mode even while charger is connected

Tags: laptop, power-supply, windows-11, battery, power

I have an Acer e5-576g laptop. I used this laptop as a PC and it is always connected to AC power. Up until recently my battery even though it was weak worked and because I was always charging it was always 100%. Recently my battery completely died and the laptop no longer works without ac power.

Now the problem I am facing is even though I have disable the power saving modes on Windows 11 I believe there is an in built power saving mode in the laptop which is causing it to run on low power mode. I think how this works is if the battery is lower than 5% it goes into this mode and since my battery is dead it probably is assuming it as 0% and refuses to go out of this mode. The battery is not removable although I have disabled and uninstalled the battery drivers from the device manager.

Is there any solutions to this. Help Pls. I have another laptop for work and I only use this one for gaming hence I don't want to bother replacing the battery as it never will be used anyways. I am open to downgrading to an older version of windows if it might help fix this issue.

Update: I have manage to open the laptop and remove the battery completely and it has not fixed the issue.

Comment: Windows 11 is not supported in your hardware therefore problems are to be expected.

Comment: Its a laptop after all, its firmware is designed for that.

Comment: You might have to replace the battery to make it work, but they're available for US$20 or so: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Acer+e5-576g+battery

Answer (score 0):

Your computer does not work (or at least not properly) without a battery. That is common with newer computers.

You should be able to get a replacement battery from Acer or from Dr Battery (Amazon).

I have successfully done the latter and the computer works fine with the replacement battery.

You may find this a good time to replace the computer.

Comment: I have removed my battery completely from my laptop by opening it. Laptop still is working just not at full power. Additionally, I already have a seperate device for most of my important work I only use this for gaming as my other device does not have a dedicated gpu. I can't really afford to get one with a gpu and since im not intending to use the battery anyways I am hoping to bypass this issue if possible